# Point at Infinity of E.C. in Jacobian Coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am reading some notes about elliptic curves right now and the author mentions the alternative Jacobian projective coordinates, where one establishes the equivalence $(x,y,z)\sim (\lambda^2 x, \lambda^3 y, \lambda z)$ so that the homogeneous general equation of the elliptic curve is $y^2=x^3+Axz^4+Bz^6$. The author then states that the point at infinity is $[0:1:0]$ just as in usual coordinates.

This is a mistake, right? The point $[0:1:0]$ is not on that curve; the point at infinity should be $[1:1:0]$, no?

Comment: Are these notes online, so we may have a look?

Comment: page 7 here: http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/LectureNotes6.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $[0:1:0]$ is not on the curve $y^2=x^3+Axz^4+Bz^6$ in those modified projective coordinates $[x:y:z]$, and $[1:1:0]$ is indeed on the curve. I am not an expert though in cryptography... the literature in cryptography seems to insist in calling the point at infinity by $[0:1:0]$ even though this point is not on the curve in those coordinates (see [this book for example](https://books.google.com/books?id=kb7ZzFrJi48C&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=jacobian%20coordinates%20point%20at%20infinity&source=bl&ots=T941ooC3gk&sig=eBloCBNSb1eVtkFhnoaEzCHUVaY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dms-VYzhHMW1yASWs4GYAw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=jacobian%20coordinates%20point%20at%20infinity&f=false)). So it might be the case that calling the point at infinity $[0:1:0]$ is just a label (referring to the usual projective coordinates) and not meaning to imply that $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=0$ satisfy the modified equation. It seems, however, that [some books do not follow this confusing 'convention'](https://books.google.com/books?id=nBfCEqpYKW0C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=jacobian%20coordinates%20point%20at%20infinity&source=bl&ots=sK3qXeHbrS&sig=vkHgHUEi9GwXQvV9ak01qz5EoSo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dms-VYzhHMW1yASWs4GYAw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=jacobian%20coordinates%20point%20at%20infinity&f=false) if that's really the case.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy.